# Как можно смоделировать сеть

Tags: c#, сеть, oracle11g

Как смоделировать сеть состоящую из сервера и нескольких рабочих машин,с возможностью моделирования скорости сети. Что использовать WmWare? Это нужно для проверки работы готового приложения сетевого.

Comment: [gns3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Network_Simulator-3) поглядите

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я могу построить на этой штук виртуальную сеть с машинами на которых будет стоить мой проверяемый софт?

Comment: Сеть сможите построить

Comment: VmWare, Virtualbox, Qemu и [Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994863/how-to-use-docker-or-linux-containers-for-network-emulation)